# Any way to see the global list of keyboard shortcuts on my mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mountain-lion

I had an iTunes app called Synergy, which I assigned the keyboard shortcut ctrl+cmd+up/down. I don't use this app any more, but I'm unable to use this shortcut in Xcode, so there must be something interfering with it.

Is there a defaults property list anywhere where I can check if the shortcut is still reserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the `System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts` tab to see the assigned shortcuts and delete them.

You can also detect conflicts in keyboard shortcuts by following the instructions at the page (it says "Lion" but may apply to "Mountain Lion" as well): [OS X Lion: If a keyboard shortcut doesn’t work](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH4182)

You may have deleted the Synergy app from your Applications folder but not deleted the Preference (plist) file for it, which is where the custom shortcuts would be stored. The Preference file is usually located in `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/Preferences/`, and for this specific case, the file should be with something like `com.wincent.synergy.plist` (assuming Synergy is from wincent.com). Deleting that file may help.

Comment: Great. Cheers. I've already cleared out the synergy preferences, and checked Sys Prefs, so I'll give that second option a go.